# QTableView does not get the Background color of the central widget

Tags: qt, background-color, qtableview

[image]

I have a QMainWindow.

To that window, I've set a Central Widget.

I have a Vertical Box Layout, and have added some widgets to the Layout, including a QTableView.

I've set this Layout to the Central Widget and have set a Background colour for this widget.

Problem is..while the other widgets acquire this background colour, the TableView remains resolutely in White.

Could anyone please tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use stylesheets in order to apply the background color to all widgets. The following will work:

```
*{
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    alternate-background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

For more details check the [Qt Style Sheet documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html) and the [StyleSheets reference](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-reference.html). For examples have a look [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks. Looked at stylesheets and their working. Seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try new the QWidget inherit from the Central Widget,that is:

```
QTableView* myTable = new QTableView(ui->centralWidget());
```

Comment: I did that. 

Inherited myTable from CentralWidget, and then defined a colour for the centralWidget. Didn't work.